# >AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' (in a lowercase dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, lowercase

I don't understand this error... I've already turned df into lowercase before turning it into a list

dataframe:

```
    all_cols
0   who is your hero and why
1   what do you do to relax
2   this is a hero
4   how many hours of sleep do you get a night
5   describe the last time you were relax
```

Code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

df['all_cols'] = df['all_cols'].str.lower()
df_list = df.values.tolist()

pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
('trans', FunctionTransformer(lambda x: x.todense(), accept_sparse=True)),
('clust', MeanShift())])

pipeline.fit(df_list)
pipeline.named_steps['clust'].labels_

result = [(label,doc) for doc,label in zip(df_list, pipeline.named_steps['clust'].labels_)]

for label,doc in sorted(result):
    print(label, doc)
```

But I have an error in this line:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in
>
> ----> 1 pipeline.fit(df_list)
>
> ```
>  2 pipeline.named_steps['clust'].labels_
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

But why is the program returning a lowercase error if I've already passed the lowercase dataframe before?

Comment: Are you sure all rows are strings not lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specified column for `df_list` for avoid nested lists:

```
df_list = df.values.tolist()
print (df_list)
[['who is your hero and why'], 
 ['what do you do to relax'], 
 ['this is a hero'], 
 ['how many hours of sleep do you get a night'], 
 ['describe the last time you were relax']]
```

---

```
df_list = df['all_cols'].values.tolist()
print (df_list)
['who is your hero and why', 
 'what do you do to relax', 
 'this is a hero',
 'how many hours of sleep do you get a night',
 'describe the last time you were relax']
```

Answer (score 4):

Convert it into pandas data frame and then do the operation you are doing above. It will work.
I have still pasted the snippet and you can try yourself.

```
import pandas as pd

col = pd.Series(["who is your hero and why", "what do you do to relax", "this is a hero", "how many hours of sleep do you get a night", "describe the last time you were relax"])
fr = {"all_cols":col}
df = pd.DataFrame(fr)
df['all_cols'] = df['all_cols'].str.lower()
df_list = df.values.tolist()
```